# Newer Firebase Node.js SDK initialization does not work - older version does

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When using the Firebase Node.js SDK to write data, I get `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` in the browser and `The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services.` in the console. Yet when I use the old way, it works.

New code:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert("<my-account>.json"),
  databaseURL: "https://<my-project>.firebaseio.com"
});
```

Old code (working):

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

firebase.initializeApp({
  serviceAccount: "<my-config>.json",
  databaseURL: "https://<my-project>.firebaseio.com"
});
```

I get the deprecation warning when using the old code, but it writes to Firebase nonetheless.

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me with the newer version of Firebase:

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```